# How to hide Chrome's three dot menu in PWAs

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

So, I was just playing around with PWAs on CRA. So far, I had success in making the app installable on windows. Everything is fine but the only thing that's stopping the app from having a native look is the chrome's three dot menu and the extensions icon. I came upon [this post on quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-three-dot-menu-icon-in-a-PWA-on-Chrome), where the answers say to make the `display: standalone` in manifest. I tried it, but in vain. Here's what I want to remove:

[image]

A snapshot of the Chrome DevTools shows that the display is already in `standalone` mode:

[image]

Comment: That is Chrome desktop being helpful to the user. I do not think you can remove it. It may also show extensions they have installed. As a curiosity, why do you want to remove this helpful functionality?

Comment: @Mathias Just to make the app look more 'native', to make it look as if it wasn't just a webpage but what most users call a 'real desktop app'

Comment: OK, I understand, thanks.

Comment: you could set display to `fullscreen`